# TableRow cells Collection set attribute

Tags: html, dom

I'm looping through a table in the form of table.rows.length and inside it rows.cells.length and when a certain cell meets a certain criteria then I would like to set an attribute to that html of that cell.

I know you can change the innerHTMl like

```
var x = document.getElementById("myTable").rows[0].cells;
x[0].innerHTML = "NEW CONTENT";
```

so I thought the attr would be like

```
x[0].attr = ('name', 'value');
```

But no such luck.

could someone please point me to the right direction?

If there are any resources you can recommend that give a full list of all the options you can add to a cell this way that would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're operating with HTML nodes directly - you're dealing with [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) objects that are, in their turn, inherited from generic [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element).

As you can see from documentation - you can reach attributes through [Element.attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes) map, each of them are [Attr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Attr) object with `name` and `value` properties.

So correct way will be to use:

```
x[0].setAttribute('name', 'value');
```

Comment: thanks, but that doesn't seem to create an attribute on the table cell, is that for amending a value on the table cell if that attribute already exists?

Comment: You may try to use [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) method instead, I'm not sure if `attributes` collection is writable

Comment: That's the one! thank you, if you update your answer I'll mark it as worked

Answer (score 1):

Working with jQuery and es6 syntax you could use the map function:

```
var xtr = $('#mytable tr');
xtr.map(itr => {
    xtd = $(itr).children('td');
    xtd.map(itd => {
        $(itd).attr('key', 'value');
    });
});
```

If thats confusing you can work with the for loop the old way:

```
var xtr = $('#mytable tr');
for(i in xtr){
    xtd = $(xtr[i]).children('td');
    for(j in xtd){
        $(xtd[j]).attr('key', 'value');
    }
}
```

Point being when using jQuery what you do is:

```
$('element').attr('key', 'value');
```